# create pivot table from vendor name

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have this query:

```
------------WITH THE 'WITH' CLAULE
USE [VERPLOEGEN-NAV2009-LIVE]
SELECT 
    SU.[Vendor No_] as LeveranciersNR, V.Name as LeveranciersName, 
    SU.[Item No_], SU.[Reorder Cycle] as bestelfrequentie,
    SU.[Location Code], SU.[Reordering Policy], 
    I.Description as procuctOmschrijving,
    SUM(VLE.[Purchase (LCY)]) as Inkoopomzet
FROM 
    [Verploegen POC$Vendor] V
JOIN
    [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry] VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
    AND VLE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
JOIN 
    [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit] SU ON V.No_ = SU.[Vendor No_]
    AND SU.[Reordering Policy] = 2 
JOIN 
    [Verploegen POC$Item] I ON I.No_ = SU.[Item No_]
GROUP BY 
    VLE.[Vendor No_], SU.[Vendor No_], V.Name, SU.[Item No_], 
    SU.[Reorder Cycle], SU.[Location Code], SU.[Reordering Policy],
    I.Description
ORDER BY v.Name ASC
    --SU.[Location Code]
```

And I want to make a pivot of it, where you have vendor name: and then by every location code: DB', 'DL', 'AM','RD','ZM. you can see the total of products that is ordered by the vendor. AND the frequenty for every vendor.

I try it like this:

```
------------WITH THE 'WITH' CLAULE
USE [VERPLOEGEN-NAV2009-LIVE]
SELECT 
    ptt.Name --as LeveranciersName 

FROM 
(SELECT SU.[Item No_], [Reorder Cycle] as bestelfrequentie,
    SU.[Location Code], SU.[Reordering Policy] FROM Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit SU 
    JOIN [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry] VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
    AND VLE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
    JOIN  [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit] SU ON V.No_ = SU.[Vendor No_]
    AND SU.[Reordering Policy] = 2
    JOIN  [Verploegen POC$Item] I ON I.No_ = SU.[Item No_]
    ) AS V
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(VLE.[Purchase (LCY)]) as Inkoopomzet        
        FOR V.Location Code IN ('DB', 'DL', 'AM','RD','ZM') 

    )AS ptt
    ORDER BY ptt.Location Code 
    --[Verploegen POC$Vendor] V

--JOIN
--    [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry] VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
--    AND VLE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
--JOIN 
--    [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit] SU ON V.No_ = SU.[Vendor No_]
--    AND SU.[Reordering Policy] = 2 
--JOIN 
--    [Verploegen POC$Item] I ON I.No_ = SU.[Item No_]
--GROUP BY 
--    VLE.[Vendor No_], SU.[Vendor No_], V.Name, SU.[Item No_], 
--    SU.[Reorder Cycle], SU.[Location Code], SU.[Reordering Policy],
--    I.Description
--ORDER BY v.Name ASC
    --SU.[Location Code]
```

Thank you

For the normal query the output is like this:

```
3306    ADW Groothandel bv  224023  2M  AM  2   a3871130 designsifon chr. 1 1/  -41351.06000000000000000000
3306    ADW Groothandel bv  224023  2M  DB  2   a3871130 designsifon chr. 1 1/  -41351.06000000000000000000
3306    ADW Groothandel bv  224023  2M  DL  2   a3871130 designsifon chr. 1 1/  -41351.06000000000000000000
3306    ADW Groothandel bv  224023  2M  RD  2   a3871130 designsifon chr. 1 1/  -41351.06000000000000000000
3306    ADW Groothandel bv  224023  2M  ZM  2   a3871130 designsifon chr. 1 1/  -41351.06000000000000000000
3306    ADW Groothandel bv  224276  2M  AM  2   adwastafelplug 5/4 click bedie  -41351.06000000000000000000
3306    ADW Groothandel bv  224276  2M  DB  2   adwastafelplug 5/4 click bedie  -41351.06000000000000000000
```

IF I Try it like this:

```
------------WITH THE 'WITH' CLAULE
USE [VERPLOEGEN-NAV2009-LIVE]
SELECT 
    V.[Location Code] --as LeveranciersName 

FROM 
(SELECT SU.[Item No_], SU.[Reorder Cycle] as bestelfrequentie,
    SU.[Location Code], SU.[Reordering Policy] FROM [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit] SU 
    JOIN [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry] VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
    AND VLE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
    --JOIN  [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit]  ON I.No_ = SU.[Vendor No_]
    AND SU.[Reordering Policy] = 2
    JOIN  [Verploegen POC$Item] I ON I.No_ = SU.[Item No_]
    ) AS V
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(VLE.[Purchase (LCY)])       
        FOR V.Location Code IN ([DB], [DL], [AM], [RD], [ZM])

    )AS ptt
    ORDER BY ptt.Location Code 
    --[Verploegen POC$Vendor] V

I get errors on this line:

JOIN [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry] VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
```

V.No_
and on this line:

```
FOR V.Location Code IN ([DB], [DL], [AM], [RD], [ZM])
```

I have it now like this:

--------------WITH THE 'WITH' CLAULE

```
--USE [VERPLOEGEN-NAV2009-LIVE]
--SELECT 
--    --V.[Location Code] --as LeveranciersName 
--  *

--FROM 
--(SELECT SU.[Item No_], SU.[Reorder Cycle] as bestelfrequentie,
--    SU.[Location Code], SU.[Reordering Policy] FROM [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit] SU 
--  JOIN [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry] VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
--    AND VLE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
--  --JOIN  [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit]  ON I.No_ = SU.[Vendor No_]
--    AND SU.[Reordering Policy] = 2
--  JOIN  [Verploegen POC$Item] I ON I.No_ = SU.[Item No_]
--  ) AS V
--  PIVOT
--  (
--      SUM(VLE.[Purchase (LCY)])       
--      --FOR V.Location Code IN ([DB], [DL], [AM], [RD], [ZM])
--      FOR [Verploegen POC$Vendor]  

--  )AS ptt
--  ORDER BY ptt.Location Code 
--    --[Verploegen POC$Vendor] V
--  ------------------------------------
---

------------WITH THE 'WITH' CLAULE
USE [VERPLOEGEN-NAV2009-LIVE]
SELECT 
    --V.[Location Code] --as LeveranciersName 
    *

FROM 
(SELECT 
    V.Name as LeveranciersName, V.No_, 
    --SU.[Item No_], SU.[Reorder Cycle] as bestelfrequentie,
    --SU.[Location Code], SU.[Reordering Policy], 

    SUM(VLE.[Purchase (LCY)]) as Inkoopomzet
FROM 
    [Verploegen POC$Vendor] V 
    JOIN [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry] VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
    AND VLE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
    JOIN 
    [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit] SU ON V.No_ = SU.[Vendor No_]
    AND SU.[Reordering Policy] = 2   
    JOIN  [Verploegen POC$Item] I ON I.No_ = SU.[Item No_]

    ) AS V
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(V.Inkoopomzet)
        --SUM([Purchase (LCY)]) 
        --FOR  Location Code IN ([DB], [DL], [AM], [RD], [ZM])
        --FOR [Verploegen POC$Activity]  
        FOR V.No_ in ([33605])

        --FOR [Verploegen POC$Vendor]


    )AS ptt
    --ORDER BY ptt.Location Code 
    --[Verploegen POC$Vendor] V
```

but then I get the error:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Column 'Verploegen POC$Vendor.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I have it now like this. And it seems correct:

```
USE [VERPLOEGEN-NAV2009-LIVE]
SELECT 
    --V.[Location Code] --as LeveranciersName 
    *

FROM 
(SELECT 
    V.Name as LeveranciersName, V.No_,SU.[Reorder Cycle] as frequentie
    ,SU.[Location Code] as location, V.[Freight-free Limit] AS vreievracht ,
    --SU.[Item No_], SU.[Reorder Cycle] as bestelfrequentie,
    --SU.[Location Code], SU.[Reordering Policy], 

    SUM(VLE.[Purchase (LCY)]) as Inkoopomzet

FROM 
    [Verploegen POC$Vendor] V 
    JOIN [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry] VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
    AND VLE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
    JOIN 
    [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit] SU ON V.No_ = SU.[Vendor No_]
    AND SU.[Reordering Policy] = 2   
    JOIN  [Verploegen POC$Item] I ON I.No_ = SU.[Item No_]
    GROUP BY V.Name, V.No_, SU.[Location Code], su.[Reorder Cycle], V.[Freight-free Limit]

    ) AS V
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(V.Inkoopomzet)
        --SUM([Purchase (LCY)]) 
        --FOR  Location Code IN ([DB], [DL], [AM], [RD], [ZM])
        --FOR [Verploegen POC$Activity]  
        FOR location in ([AM], [DB],[DL], [RD], [ZM])

        --FOR [Verploegen POC$Vendor]


    )AS ptt
    ORDER BY LeveranciersName  
    --[Verploegen POC$Vendor] V
```

But I get this as output:

ADW Groothandel bv  3306        300.00000000000000000000    -165404.24000000000000000000    -165404.24000000000000000000    -165404.24000000000000000000    -165404.24000000000000000000    -165404.24000000000000000000

and I want to have as output. for cleaner output:

-41351.06

Hi everyone. I have it now like this:

```
USE [VERPLOEGEN-NAV2009-LIVE]
SELECT *
    --V.[Location Code] --as LeveranciersName    
FROM 
(SELECT 
    V.Name as LeveranciersName, V.No_,SU.[Reorder Cycle] as frequentie
    ,SU.[Location Code] as location,  cast( V.[Freight-free Limit] as decimal(18,1))AS Vrachtvrije_Limiet ,     
    CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(Sum(VLE.[Purchase (LCY)]), '(', '-'), ')','') AS MONEY)AS Inkoopomzet

FROM 
    [Verploegen POC$Vendor] V 
    JOIN [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry] VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
    AND VLE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
    JOIN 
    [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit] SU ON V.No_ = SU.[Vendor No_]
    AND SU.[Reordering Policy] = 2   
    JOIN  [Verploegen POC$Item] I ON I.No_ = SU.[Item No_]
    GROUP BY V.Name, V.No_, SU.[Location Code], su.[Reorder Cycle], V.[Freight-free Limit],VLE.[Purchase (LCY)] 

    ) AS V
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(V.Inkoopomzet)      
        FOR location in ([AM], [DB],[DL], [RD], [ZM])           
    )AS ptt
    ORDER BY LeveranciersName  
    --[Verploegen POC$Vendor] V
```

and it seems to work

Comment: If you change `IN ('DB', 'DL', 'AM','RD','ZM')` to `IN ([DB], [DL], [AM], [RD], [ZM])` you're probably good

Comment: Thank you. But that doesnt work

Comment: I think selecting `ptt.Name` at the top of your query is the problem. This doesn't seem appear anywhere else in your query. Maybe try selecting `[DB], [DL], [AM], [RD], [ZM]` instead.

Comment: Do you need both "total of products" and "frequenty" to be pivoted by V.Location ? PIVOT has no such capability, use plain SUM(CASE ...)

Comment: You're missing the `[]` on `FOR V.[Location Code]` inside the pivot. And outside the pivot you should then use the new columns `[DB], [DL], [AM], [RD], [ZM]`.

Comment: And what are the error messages? Can you post your expected output also? Btw, columns you don't need in the output shouldn't be selected in the source query before the pivot.

Comment: The FOR statement doesnt work at all. INcorrect syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
USE [VERPLOEGEN-NAV2009-LIVE]
SELECT *
    --V.[Location Code] --as LeveranciersName    
FROM 
(SELECT 
    V.Name as LeveranciersName, V.No_,SU.[Reorder Cycle] as frequentie
    ,SU.[Location Code] as location,  cast( V.[Freight-free Limit] as decimal(18,1))AS Vrachtvrije_Limiet ,     
    CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(Sum(VLE.[Purchase (LCY)]), '(', '-'), ')','') AS MONEY)AS Inkoopomzet

FROM 
    [Verploegen POC$Vendor] V 
    JOIN [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry] VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
    AND VLE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
    JOIN 
    [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit] SU ON V.No_ = SU.[Vendor No_]
    AND SU.[Reordering Policy] = 2   
    JOIN  [Verploegen POC$Item] I ON I.No_ = SU.[Item No_]
    GROUP BY V.Name, V.No_, SU.[Location Code], su.[Reorder Cycle], V.[Freight-free Limit],VLE.[Purchase (LCY)] 

    ) AS V
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(V.Inkoopomzet)      
        FOR location in ([AM], [DB],[DL], [RD], [ZM])           
    )AS ptt
    ORDER BY LeveranciersName  
    --[Verploegen POC$Vendor] V
```